# How to commit with --no-verify flag in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide

I always use WebStorm IDE, and I like so mush its Git manager. But for some time now I have the need to commit with `--no-verify` and I don't find anywhere how to simulate that when I commit with WebStorm.

Answer (score 7):

The key to simulate `--no-verify` flag in Jetbrains IDEs is prevent execute git hooks before commit, as I show in the picture:

[image]

unchecking that option The git manager won't execute any githooks as the same way as the `--no-verify` does.

For pre-push hooks, in the pre-push popup you must uncheck the run Git hooks like this:

[image]